# Storing output of a PS Script in a C# variable

Tags: c#, powershell, azure

I am new to C# and PowerShell.

I am working on Azure `Powershell`. I have tried numerous ways of extracting metrics, but sadly none of them have worked out. I want to display the metrics obtained through Get-`AzureRMMetricDefinition` in a text box or in a message box (will filter it later).

The code has been attached and it does not give out any output apart from the login page from Microsoft.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        String a;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void scripts()
        {
            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            runspace.Open();
            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Login-AzureRMAccount");
            Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
            runspace.Close();
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (PSObject obj in results)
            {
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
            }
            Runspace runspace1 = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            runspace1.Open();
            Pipeline pipeline1 = runspace1.CreatePipeline();
            String rid="/subscriptions/blah/blah/blah";//The ResourceID goes 
            here.
            pipeline1.Commands.AddScript("Get-AzureRMMetricDefinition -
            ResourceID \""+rid+"\"");
            Collection<PSObject> results1 = pipeline1.Invoke();
            runspace1.Close();
            StringBuilder stringBuilder1 = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (PSObject obj in results1)
            {
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
            }
            a=stringBuilder1.ToString();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            scripts();
        }


        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.textBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // textBox2
            // 
            this.textBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            this.textBox2.Multiline = true;
            this.textBox2.Name = "textBox2";
            this.textBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(729, 244);
            this.textBox2.TabIndex = 0;
            this.textBox2.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox2_TextChanged);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(753, 268);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox2);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            scripts();
            this.textBox2.Text += a;
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do a test with the following code to run [Get-AzureRmMetricDefinition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.insights/get-azurermmetricdefinition?view=azurermps-4.1.0), which works fine on my side, I can get account info and metric definitions after the code is executed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //run Login-AzureRmAccount
            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

            runspace.Open();

            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

            var scriptText = "Login-AzureRmAccount";
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);

            pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

            Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();


            runspace.Close();

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (PSObject obj in results)
            {
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
            }

            var accountinfo = stringBuilder.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine(accountinfo);


            //run Get-AzureRmMetricDefinition

            Runspace runspace1 = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

            runspace1.Open();

            Pipeline pipeline1 = runspace1.CreatePipeline();

            var subscription = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
            var resourcegroup = "xxxxx";
            var appname = "xxxxx";

            //Get metric definitions with detailed output
            var MetricDefscriptText = $"Get-AzureRmMetricDefinition -ResourceId '/subscriptions/{subscription}/resourceGroups/{resourcegroup}/providers/microsoft.web/sites/{appname}' -DetailedOutput";
            pipeline1.Commands.AddScript(MetricDefscriptText);


            pipeline1.Commands.Add("Out-String");

            Collection<PSObject> Metrics = pipeline1.Invoke();


            runspace1.Close();

            StringBuilder stringBuilder1 = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (PSObject obj in Metrics)
            {
                stringBuilder1.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
            }

            var metricdefinitions = stringBuilder1.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(metricdefinitions);
        }
    }
}
```

***Output:***

[image]

***Same output if run it in Powershell:***

[image]

If possible, you can create a console application and do a test with the code that I shared, and check whether it works on your side.

Comment: It does help me out. The issue is that the minute that it displays the metrics, it exits out of the console. Is it supposed to work like that?

Comment: Excuse me for being naive. I just googled that as well, it turns out that it is the debugger. Apologies for bothering you!
Once again, thank you so much!